# utilize single datepicker function for all date picker text box

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

How to utilize single date picker jquery for all new dynamically added date picker text box

Comment: Code link is http://jsfiddle.net/9ZTXB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough fix could be made far better. But works though. Hope it helps.

The logic is to change the id dynamically with respect to the row count and initialize date picker for each input.

Your version didn't work because you just copied the html content and pasted. The datepicker needs to be initialized again to work.

```
cell1.innerHTML= '<input id="datePicker'+$(row).index()+'" /></td>';//change innerhtml
$('#datePicker'+c).kendoDatePicker({})); initialze the datepicker again.//init datepicker again
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ZTXB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you duplicating the same id for each datepicker it is better to use a class instead of id.

And since the new datepicker is created dynamically you need to call the kendoDatePicker function after creating the new datapicker.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><td><input class="datePicker" /></td></tr>
 </table>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button>


$(".datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function() {
       console.log("closed datePicker");   
    }
});


function displayResult()
{
var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
var row=table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
cell1.innerHTML=table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;    
$(".datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function() {
       console.log("closed datePicker");   
    }
});
}
```